# Construct an object from array of string

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Is there any efficient way to construct an `object` from an `array` of string in `LWC`?

```
const layerArr = ['Comp Type', 'Region', 'Industry'];
```

**OUTPUT**

```
const targetObj = [
    {
        "name": "Comp Type",
        "options": "comptypeOptions",
        "taxLabel": "comptypeLabel"
    },
    {
        "name": "Region",
        "options": "regionOptions",
        "taxLabel": "regionLabel"
    },
    {
        "name": "Industry",
        "options": "industryOptions",
        "taxLabel": "industryLabel"
    }
]
```

I am using `reduce` function but it's not woking here and also I want to use `toLowerCase()` on the fly while assigning the key too.

```
layerObject = this.layerOptions.reduce(function (result, item, index) {
    result['name'] = item;
    result['options'] = item.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase() + 'Options';
    result['taxLabel'] = item.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase() + 'Label';
    return result
}, {})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transformation can be accomplished with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let x; // Used inside callback
this.layerObject = 
  this.layerOptions.map(v => (x = v.replace(' ','').toLowerCase(), { 
    name: v, 
    options: `${x}Options`, 
    taxLabel: `${x}Label`
  }));
```

Some notes:

The arrow function uses `x => y` as a notation for parameter x fed into the next expression, and y is returned as the result. However, if we want multiple lines of execution, we write `x => { y }`. To get an object literal, we need to wrap *that* in parentheses, resulting in `x => ({ y })`, which is why it's written this way in the example.

The Array.prototype.map function iterates over every item in an array, and transforms it per the callback function. We use this feature to map the string into the three-property object that you're trying to achieve.

The string in backticks (`\`) is a Template Literal, which we use to substitute expressions in without extra string concatenation. The `${...}` syntax is evaluated as a normal expression, which is how we transform the latter two properties as you desire.

The original map isn't modified when using Array.prototype.map; a new Array is returned instead.

The comma operator performs the operation on the left, then the right, and returns the value on the right.

By the way, `Array.prototype.reduce` is used to convert an array into a single object or result, such as `[1,3,5].reduce((a,b) => (a + b), 0)` to output 8 (1 + 3 + 5). It's useful in a lot of cases, but not here.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
layerObject = this.layerOptions.reduce(function (result, item) {
    let lcItem = item.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
    result.append({
        name: item,
        options: `${lcItem}Options`,
        taxLabel: `${lcItem}Label`
    });
    return result;
}, []);
```

As per your requirements you want to reduce to an Array (`[]`) and not an object (`{}`), that's the main thing.